# Cannot connect to MySQL database with Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, async-await

My app has to connect to a mysql database but i am stuck just in that moment i cant connect it, im using a method that transforms callbacks code to promise code thats the reason i need to use async and await also the man of the tutorial doesnt have any error i guess because he has diferent terms on the keys.js, he is on linux, root user and also he has a password, things that i dont have. I really need hel thank you.
This is the code that is giving problems:

```
    const express= require('express');
const router= express.Router();

const pool = require('../database');

router.get('/add', (req,res) =>{
res.render('casas/add');
});

router.post('/add',  async (req,res) => {
    const {titulo, precio, direccion, numhab, superficie} = req.body;
    const nuevoPiso={
        titulo,
        precio,
        direccion,
        numhab,
        superficie
    };

   await pool.query('INSERT INTO PISOS set ?', [nuevoPiso]);
   res.send('recibido');
});



module.exports=router;
```

The problem is on the await line because if I delete that and the async word it works perfectly but obviously without that I cant send the elements to the database. The error that gives me the terminal is this:

```
(node:9548) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: Access denied for user 'Axell'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
    at Handshake.Sequence._packetToError (C:\Users\Axell\Desktop\node-sql-app\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:47:14)
    at Handshake.ErrorPacket (C:\Users\Axell\Desktop\node-sql-app\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Handshake.js:123:18)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (C:\Users\Axell\Desktop\node-sql-app\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:291:23)
    at Parser._parsePacket (C:\Users\Axell\Desktop\node-sql-app\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:433:10)
    at Parser.write (C:\Users\Axell\Desktop\node-sql-app\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:43:10)
    at Protocol.write (C:\Users\Axell\Desktop\node-sql-app\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:38:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Axell\Desktop\node-sql-app\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:88:28)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Axell\Desktop\node-sql-app\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:526:10)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:311:20)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:294:12)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (C:\Users\Axell\Desktop\node-sql-app\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:144:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (C:\Users\Axell\Desktop\node-sql-app\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:51:23)
    at PoolConnection.connect (C:\Users\Axell\Desktop\node-sql-app\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:116:18)
    at Pool.getConnection (C:\Users\Axell\Desktop\node-sql-app\node_modules\mysql\lib\Pool.js:48:16)
    at Pool.query (C:\Users\Axell\Desktop\node-sql-app\node_modules\mysql\lib\Pool.js:202:8)
    at internal/util.js:297:30
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Pool.query (internal/util.js:296:12)
    at C:\Users\Axell\Desktop\node-sql-app\src\routes\casas.js:20:15
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Axell\Desktop\node-sql-app\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
(node:9548) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This 
error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch 
block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:9548) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
POST /casas/add - - ms - -
(node:9548) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: Access denied for user 'Axell'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
    at Handshake.Sequence._packetToError (C:\Users\Axell\Desktop\node-sql-app\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:47:14)
    at Handshake.ErrorPacket (C:\Users\Axell\Desktop\node-sql-app\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Handshake.js:123:18)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (C:\Users\Axell\Desktop\node-sql-app\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:291:23)
    at Parser._parsePacket (C:\Users\Axell\Desktop\node-sql-app\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:433:10)
    at Parser.write (C:\Users\Axell\Desktop\node-sql-app\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:43:10)
    at Protocol.write (C:\Users\Axell\Desktop\node-sql-app\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:38:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Axell\Desktop\node-sql-app\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:88:28)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Axell\Desktop\node-sql-app\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:526:10)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:311:20)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:294:12)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (C:\Users\Axell\Desktop\node-sql-app\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:144:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (C:\Users\Axell\Desktop\node-sql-app\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:51:23)
    at PoolConnection.connect (C:\Users\Axell\Desktop\node-sql-app\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:116:18)
    at Pool.getConnection (C:\Users\Axell\Desktop\node-sql-app\node_modules\mysql\lib\Pool.js:48:16)
    at Pool.query (C:\Users\Axell\Desktop\node-sql-app\node_modules\mysql\lib\Pool.js:202:8)
    at internal/util.js:297:30
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Pool.query (internal/util.js:296:12)
    at C:\Users\Axell\Desktop\node-sql-app\src\routes\casas.js:20:15
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Axell\Desktop\node-sql-app\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
(node:9548) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This 
error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch 
block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)
POST /casas/add - - ms - -
```

I dont know where the error is maybe on my keys.js where i have this im on windows that is my username but I dont have a password:

```
module.exports={


    database:{
        host:'localhost',
        user:'Axell',
        database: 'casas',
        password: ''
    }

};
```

Here you can download the whole app it is unfinished because I cant continue due to this error: https://mega.nz/#!LAwgwAQK!OiuBqH4qxyT5CW2xRSUXdmhpfRyTtf3TobmYw-NqIic

Thank you so much!

Comment: Please look at your post, hit the edit button, and fix thos formatting problems. Also, please slim this down: don't make people download your app, instead you're expected to put in a little bit more work and form a [mcve] yourself, which doesn't just let others help you, but often makes you find the problem entirely on your own, because the exercise of forming an MCVE forces you to more closely consider what is, and what isn't related to your problem, and which dynamic long-codepath-inputs you can actually entirely hardcode as a single `const` value, etc.

Comment: I don't think it's related to async/await.  It's related to DB permissions.  If you want to double check, rewrite your `await` to `pool.query('INSERT INTO PISOS set ?', [nuevoPiso]).then(() => res.send('recibido'))`.

Comment: the error is `Error: ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: Access denied for user 'Axell'@'localhost' (using password: NO)` - now you know where the error is - it's common practice to have `await` inside a try/catch so you can handle errors in your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you are having is unrelated to async/await.

The credentials to MySQL incorrect. This could be an incorrect username, an incorrect password or perhaps you did not grant the `Axell` permission to access the `casas` database.

Given that you're on localhost, you can test this without localhost. Just try logging on with the same credentials with some other mysql tool (such as the `mysql`) tool, and you should get a similar error.